# One IP is not reachable unless creating a dummy route

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, routing, ping

One host can ping everything but one other host.

Let's say that I've 4 hosts in my network:

1. My Internet Box (Gateway) : 192.168.0.100
2. My Ubuntu machine : 192.168.0.1
3. My RPi machine : 192.168.0.2
4. My Tuya WiFi plug : 192.168.0.3

Ping from Ubuntu to any other hosts is working
Ping from RPi to other hosts is working **but to the Tuya plug**.

Trying to ping is 100% packet loss

```
pi@hassbian:~ $ ping 192.168.0.3
PING 192.168.0.3 (192.168.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.0.3 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 8339ms
```

But, when creating a useless route like so

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.0.3 via 192.168.0.100 dev wlan0
```

it is working, somehow

```
pi@hassbian:~ $ ping 192.168.0.3
PING 192.168.0.3 (192.168.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=80.2 ms
From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.0.3)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=122 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=144 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=4 ttl=255 time=37.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=6 ttl=255 time=61.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=7 ttl=255 time=98.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=8 ttl=255 time=119 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=9 ttl=255 time=128 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.3 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 8 received, +1 errors, 11.1111% packet loss, time 8040ms
```

After that I can remove the route and it is still working for a few minutes and fail again.

```
pi@hassbian:~ $ ip route del 192.168.0.3 via 192.168.0.100 dev wlan0
pi@hassbian:~ $ ping 192.168.0.3
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=51.6 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=54.6 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=8.64 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=32.5 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.3 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3006ms
```

The RPi is running Pi-Hole but disabling or even removing it doesn't solve the issue.

```
pi@hassbian:~ $ nslookup 192.168.0.3
3.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa       name = bf3961a448a2979f55sean.lan.
```

Running tshark confirms that request is sent but no reply is received

```
pi@hassbian:~ $ sudo tshark -i wlan0 -f "host 192.168.0.3" -f "icmp"
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on 'wlan0'
    1 0.000000000 192.168.0.2 → 192.168.0.3 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1a61, seq=6/1536, ttl=64
    2 1.040043499 192.168.0.2 → 192.168.0.3 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1a61, seq=7/1792, ttl=64
    3 2.080053454 192.168.0.2 → 192.168.0.3 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1a61, seq=8/2048, ttl=64
    4 3.120040125 192.168.0.2 → 192.168.0.3 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1a61, seq=9/2304, ttl=64
    5 4.160030649 192.168.0.2 → 192.168.0.3 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1a61, seq=10/2560, ttl=64
    6 5.200063827 192.168.0.2 → 192.168.0.3 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1a61, seq=11/2816, ttl=64
    7 6.240062420 192.168.0.2 → 192.168.0.3 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1a61, seq=12/3072, ttl=64
    8 7.280055125 192.168.0.2 → 192.168.0.3 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1a61, seq=13/3328, ttl=64
    9 8.320066109 192.168.0.2 → 192.168.0.3 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1a61, seq=14/3584, ttl=64
   10 9.360099540 192.168.0.2 → 192.168.0.3 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1a61, seq=15/3840, ttl=64
```

Of course, there is no firewall involved, everything is directly connected via WiFi to the Gateway that is also the DNS Server.

For completeness, some additional information:

Route table before adding the dummy route

```
pi@hassbian:~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.100   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
```

arp table

```
pi@hassbian:~ $ arp | grep fc:67:1f:cb:12:58
bf3961a448a2979f55sean.lan.                ether   fc:67:1f:cb:12:58   C                     wlan0
```

So I did a terribly awful workaround: I created a cron entry for root like so

```
* * * * * ip route add 192.168.0.3 via 192.168.0.100 dev wlan0 >/dev/null 2>&1;ping -c 5 192.168.0.3 >/dev/null 2>&1;ip route del 192.168.0.3 via 192.168.0.100 dev wlan0 >/dev/null 2>&1;ping -c 5 192.168.0.3 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The Tuya plug is kept reachable and I can use some python to go read the power information.

Can someone please help me understand why this RPi host (192.168.0.2) is behaving like that when accessing the plug (192.168.0.3) while other hosts on the same network can ping the plug without any issue?

I'm hopeless, I'm running out of idea. I'd like to remove this cron entry and be on a stable network situation.

Comment: It's not a dummy route; it's a functional route that makes the packets take a different path. Does the device show up in your client host's ARP cache (`ip -4 n`) after the failed ping attempts? Does it respond to `arping`? Does your packet capture show the correct "destination MAC" for the _failed_ ping attempts?

Comment: Although not technically a dummy, it appears to be functionally useless since it should have been automatically routed through existing routes. The gateway appears to be rejecting it, so I will discontinue my workaround and monitor the network for the inevitable issues. I will keep you informed.

Comment: @user1686, when ping is failing : host is in arp cache (and show as REACHABLE), arping is working, the mac in tshark is the mac in the arp cache. Even after succesful arping, ping is still failing.

Comment: @Peregrino69, those routes were there since the first boot of my RPi. I tried to remove that one but completely lost the connection with my RPi, had to plug a screen and keyboard to recover.

Comment: ... I'm sorry for that, you're right, I embarrassingly SSHd into wrong RasPi running DietPi to check the routing table...